ValueError: The view cart.views.cart_add didn't return an HttpResponse object
I am sure this may have been addressed. I am having this issue for the past week and cannot get past it. I have tried all possible solutions in every site I could find.
Here is my error:
ValueError: The view cart.views.cart_add didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

This is my code:
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .cart import Cart
from store.models import Product
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django import template
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse



def cart_summary(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'summary.html', {'cart': cart})


def cart_add(request):
    # Get the Cart
    cart = Cart(request)
    # test to POST
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':

        # get Stuff
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        # lookup product in DB
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        # save to Session
        cart.add(product=product)

        # Return a reponse
        cart_quantity = cart.__len__()

        # Return Repesponse
        # response = JsonResponse({'Product Name ': product.name})
        response = HttpResponse({'qty ': cart_quantity})
        return response


def cart_delete(request):
    return

def cart_update(request):   
    pass

I have tried everything under the sun

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This can happen if the condition if request.POST.get('action') == 'post': is not met, causing the function to reach the end without returning a response.
The way you're creating the HttpResponse with a dictionary is incorrect. You should use JsonResponse if you want to return JSON data, or HttpResponse for plain text or HTML.
Make Sure your cart_quantity contain integer or string otherwise it will Show None.
    # Check if the request is POST and contains 'action' == 'post'
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
              # remaining code here


1. return JsonResponse({'qty': cart_quantity})
2. return Response(data={'qty': cart_quantity})


Thank you Tanveer. It worked. Much appreciated.
